# Justify-Center not in center position

Tags: html, css

I want the titles to match in the center of the batch. The title of the page is shown correctly, the breadcrumb is not. It is slightly off center to the right.

It obviously counts a padding or margin where there isn't any.

What did I do wrong here?

I just seem not to be able to figure ist all out.

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  }
  
   #page {
     position: relative;
     display: block;
     width: 950px;
     margin: auto;
     background: #fbfbfb;
     }

     #breadcrumb {
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       padding: 30px 0 0 0;
       }

     #breadcrumb li {
        margin-left: 15px;     
        }

     #breadcrumb ul { 
       margin: 0px;
/* Ungenauigkeit entsteht durch justify-content, aber warum? */
       display: -webkit-flexbox;       
       display: -ms-flexbox;           
       display: -webkit-flex;          
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row; 
       justify-content: center;
       text-align: center;
       align-items: center; 
       }

     #page_titel {
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       }

     #page_titel h1 {
       text-align: center;
       }

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="page">
   <div id="breadcrumb">
          <ul>
                        <li>Startseite</li>
                        <li>Universal Estate </li>
                </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="page_titel">
     <h1> TITEL DER SEITE </h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `padding:0` to the `ul`. Lists have a left-padding by default.

Comment: To not have troubles in the future, I always recommend to reset all padding and margin for all elements and give a border-box as box-sizing. `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }` Add this to top of your CSS code.

Answer (score 0):

The ul tag adds padding to the left. You can add the following css to remove it.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following style to your ul

```
#breadcrumb ul {
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

```
#breadcrumb ul {
padding:0;
}

#breadcrumb ul li:first-child {
margin-left:0;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you so much, this one did the trick!